# Android makes the connection to PHP file using volley but Toast error message is not specified

Tags: php, android, http, android-volley

I'm using volley to do the request with the next code (which is executed by pressing a button):

```
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_POST, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),error+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("name",n);

            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(sr);
```

> When the request is done I get "Error" from Toast but it's not specified what kind of error this is. I tried Google-ing the Logcat errors and none of them worked. 
> This are the Logcat errors:
>
> KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
>    D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
>    I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false

I debbuged the project to see where the mistake and I found that after doing these two lines:

```
  RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
  requestQueue.add(sr);
```

**requestQueue is still null. How can this be possible?**

I've tried using a phone which is not Samsung for this error:

> KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false D/ViewRootImpl:

And it hasn't work either

Comment: you are calling the Request queue inside of a fragment or what?

Comment: I think i'm not. If you mean an interface I'm not doing that. I'm calling this method from a Java class